# Android local Db to XML to mySql via PHP.

Tags: php, android, mysql, xml, android-sqlite

I have an application with a local Sqlite database which stores records on the local phone. Now I want to increase functionality and I have come to the conclusion that I need a remote database and server based functionality to make my application more interactive. Also at this juncture I don't want my users to lose data due to this transformation. After research and lookup over the internet I came to know that I can achieve this by writing a web-service which will fetch records row by row and feed into my mySQL database. However I am confused about how to achieve this, do I convert the local databases into XML file(s) and POST them to my PHP where I parse them and feed into mySQL database or there is a better way or rather an API for this? I want a starting point, a heading. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. As you say, convert local db to XML or JSON and POST it to server. Do not forget use gzip when transfer.
2. You can upload the db file directly to server. Your db file locate in /data/data/app-package-name/databases. You should parse this db file in server.

Comment: Could you explain more on the second point you made, this seems more credible.